# Commutative rings has Invariant Basis Number

Tags: ring-theory, modules

How can I show that every commutative ring has Invariant Basis Number?

Comment: Factor by a maximal ideal. Use the case for fields.

Comment: Well, just to eliminate the edge case, if necessary, “all commutative rings except the zero ring.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have that $R^n\cong R^m$ and as $R$ has a maximal ideal we have a surjective ring morphism $\phi \colon R\longrightarrow K$ with $K$ a field. Then $K^n\cong K^m$ as $K$-vector space, as the fields have invariant basis number it follows that $n=m$.